# How can I make a remote table in MS Access "write only"?

Tags: ms-access, permissions

I have a little MS Access application (I know, I know), which accesses a table on a remote MS SQL Server.

I also have a form, which allows the users to enter data into the table. The problem is, that I want the users not to be able to read or modify existing data, but I only want them to enter data and store it (the data is a bit sensitive).

I tried to grant only INSERT privileges to the user connecting to the database, resulting in the error, that the table is not accessible at all.

After googling, I couldn't find anything which would solve this issue.

So my question: How can I ensure, that the users only enter data, but do not modify or read existing data in MS Access (2003)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally here's what I've done:

First, I created two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE mydata (...)
CREATE TABLE mydata2 (...)
```

Then I created an `INSTEAD OF` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger ON mydata 
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
   INSERT INTO mydata2 SELECT * FROM INSERTED
END
```

This moved every single entry from mydata to mydata2 on insert. The form in Access remained on mydata though, which made the entries invisible to the user.

*Thanks to CodeSlave, who also suggested this solution*

Answer (score 3):

I would remove select permissions from the table (as you already have done) and do all the IO through a stored procedure. That way you can control exactly what is inserted into the system

Let me know if you need help running a stored procedure in ADO and I will post something up

Comment: This is the direction I would go as well. If it make it easier, you could dump the new record into a staging table, with a trigger on it to import it into the secure table immediately after it was added to the staging table - and then delete it from the staging table in the trigger.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer a stored proc, but thought this was an alternate to give access to a view of the table with a check option

```
create table testview (somevalue varchar(25), entereddate datetime)
go
insert into testview values( 'First Value', getdate() )

go
create view testview_currentonly
as 
SELECT 
    somevalue
   , entereddate
FROM testview
WHERE entereddate >= getdate()

with check option
-- end view create
go
insert into testview_currentonly values( 'Second Value', getdate() )

select * from testview_currentonly

select * from testview
```

You can't select anything from this view because all entries (assuming the user could not manipulate the value going into the 'entereddate' field (probably should have a default?).

Answer (score 1):

For the identity principal you use to access the remote SQL server table (this will be defined in the link), remove all permissions except `db_datareader`.

<strike>You can do this with MS Access permissions (but be warned: it's quite a difficult area...):</strike>

[Microsoft Access Database Security - Security Permissions](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/permissions.html)

[Types of permissions (MDB)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/types-of-permissions-mdb-HP005188594.aspx)